# How to fix the error `self` does not live long enough when creating a new value that references self?

Tags: rust

I am working in Rust, and I am having some trouble getting the ownership system to work for me.  I want to give `child` a reference to its `parent` when the `parent` creates the `child`.  Below is the code that I was trying to get working:

```
struct Child<'a> {
    parent: &'a Parent,
}
impl<'a> Child<'a> {
    fn new(parent: &Parent) -> Child {
        Child { parent: &parent }
    }
}

struct Parent {
    child_count: u32,
}
impl Parent {
    fn new() -> Parent {
        Parent { child_count: 0 }
    }
    fn makeChild(&mut self) -> Child {
        self.child_count += 1;
        Child::new(&self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut parent = Parent::new();
    let child = parent.makeChild();
}
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
src/main.rs:20:17: 20:21 error: `self` does not live long enough
src/main.rs:20     Child::new(&self)
```

Comment: Note that the Rust style for variables and methods is `snake_case`, not `camelCase`.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  However the answer below uses it again, so I'll leave it here so it's consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is already a reference, because you declare the function's argument as `&mut self`, so you don't need to take a reference to it – just use `self` directly.

```
impl Parent {
    fn new() -> Parent {
        Parent { child_count: 0 }
    }
    fn makeChild(&mut self) -> Child {
        self.child_count += 1;
        Child::new(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's only the tip of the iceberg, though. With the OP's code, he won't get a second child... (concurrently).